# Importing stldecompose result in error - cannot import name '_maybe_get_pandas_wrapper_freq' from 'statsmodels.tsa.filters._utils'

Tags: python, statsmodels

My code

```
!pip install stldecompose

from stldecompose import decompose
```

Error Msg

> ---
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>         2 # Install the library via PIP
>         3 get_ipython().system('pip install stldecompose')
>   ----> 4 from stldecompose import decompose, forecast
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stldecompose/**init**.py in 
>   ----> 1 from .stl import decompose, forecast
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stldecompose/stl.py in 
>         3 from pandas.core.nanops import nanmean as pd_nanmean
>         4 from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import DecomposeResult
>   ----> 5 from statsmodels.tsa.filters._utils import _maybe_get_pandas_wrapper_freq
>         6 import statsmodels.api as sm
>         7
>
> ImportError: cannot import name '_maybe_get_pandas_wrapper_freq' from 'statsmodels.tsa.filters._utils' (/Users/georgeng/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/filters/_utils.py)

Answer (score 4):

You have two pathway to go about this:

1. If you are running `statsmodels==0.11.0`, `statsmodels.tsa.filters._utils` function was removed from the library.

Alternatively you may use `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL`, which gives similar functionality. See its documentation:
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.html#statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL

2. Downgrade to `pip install statsmodels==0.10.2`

Comment: Downgrading options doesn't solve the issue, although indeed that's what was suggested in the relevant Github issue: https://github.com/jrmontag/STLDecompose/issues/17

Comment: A note: This answer was written in 2020, tried, tested and worked. But it might not now, please refer the official documentation for an accurate troubleshooting steps

Comment: It's ok to use `from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import STL`